# Using detox can you test apps outside of our application made in React Native?

Tags: react-native, email, emulation, detox, e2e

I'm using React Native to develop my app. I use detox as my E2E testing framework.

I want to test things outside of my app, for example:

- Browser search and deep-linking to my app.
- Email sending in Gmail/outlook app when it opens from my app.
- Photo gallery opening.
- Camera, video recording.
- (Maybe even mocking calling a number(?))

I'm using react-native 0.64.1, detox 17.8.3, jest ^26.6.3.

I don't find any info and would like to know if someone has accomplished it already.